# How to write interpretation for transformed response variable?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, interpretation

I have an average score as a response, while days and distance as independent variables. Distance is categorical with two categories: long distance and short distance.

This is my regression:

(Y)^1/2 = 4.53 + 4.92*day - 0.54*day^2 - 0.2*Short

Therefore, I have two curves:
Long distance:  (Y)^1/2 = 4.53 + 4.92*day - 0.54*day^2
Short distance: (Y)^1/2 = 4.33 + 4.92*day - 0.54*day^2

How should I make the interpretation?

Comment: Why are you taking square root of average score? If it is because of residuals not being normal, I'd use quantile regression and leave score as is.

Comment: Yes, because of residuals.

Comment: Then you should use a method that does not require normal residuals.  Quantile regression or robust regression.